# Add the average line of a serie to a chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a series of points that has fast changing values, which makes it very spiky and uneasy to read when zooming out.

I would like to know if there is a way to draw above the already existing series, another one that would represent the average of, for exemple: every 10 points, or every point in a minute?

I've looked into dataGrouping but can't seem to make it work, is that what I'm looking for ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Only one dataGrouping with `groupPixelWidth` can be applied, see [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth).

Comment: That is not what I needed, a single groupPixelWidth for every curves is logic. What it is here, is a different dataGrouping for different curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current built-in method to do this. You would need to create a second series that is the running average and add it to the chart.

The main issue here is that HS has `dataGrouping` enabled by default for all series. So, when you add your second series that has `dataGrouping` enabled with params you want - it is also applied to the initial series. You only see one series on the chart because the 2 series are identical and overlap each other.

To fix this set `dataGrouping` off in the "real" series. Then have `dataGrouping` on in the averaged series. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2u6v4/1/).

```
...
    series: [{
        name: 'MSFT',
        data: MSFT,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I get that I can't do that automatically, but when I try to add a series with different option (with chart.addSeries(options)) the first line is redrawn according to the new options. As in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2kwmS/

Comment: It does that because the series data are the same for the original one and the one you are trying to add. Try using ADBE as the added series.

Comment: I tried that before ( jsfiddle.net/2u6v4 ) and it looks like we have the same result (redrawing the first line with dataGrouping), it is clearer if you put the range selector to "all".

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. For some reason HS is treating all items as having dataGrouping on by default (there is a uservoice item on this I think). So, to fix this you need to explicitly say that the original series does NOT have dataGrouping enabled. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2u6v4/1/

Comment: Now that's it ! thank you very much. I just need to specify for each series if I don't want the pointGrouping. (if you could edit your answer with this answer it'd be nice :p ). good day !